# Vagrant box could not be found error

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrantfile, puphpet

I am trying to set up virtual machine using virtual box. I have got virtual box and vagrant installed in my windows 7 64-bit machine. I have also built an environment using puphpet. But whenever I try to install the box ubuntu1404-x64 it throws the error

```
Bringing machine 'machine1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==>Machine1: Box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
machine1: Box Provider: virtualbox
machine1: Box Version: >= 0
machine1: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
machine1: Adding box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
machine1: Downloading: puphpet/boxes/ubuntu1404-x64
machine1:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try again.
```

I checked the URL https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puphpet/boxes/ubuntu1404-x64/ and the box puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64 does exist.

Also when it says `The error message, if any, is reproduced below` it does not show any description at the terminal.

I googled the issue, tried some of the answers here at stackoverflow but no result. Please help.

Comment: I have gone through its documentation and it says there the box requires a metadata.json file in it. Now when I run vagrant up through my cmd it says box file not detected as metadata.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had a similar situation in the past, and it helped me to download the box using vagrant command line, instead of having it be downloaded automatically ( from the URL in Vagrantfile ):

```
$ vagrant box add USER/BOX
```

see more [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes.html). Could you try the same approach? It might work for you as well.

EDIT: on a windows box, Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 redist looks to be needed to perform the provisioning of the box. It can be downloaded [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328). More info on the puhpet issuet: [here](https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/2106)

Comment: Thanks for the info Geo, I looked through their documentation but the problem persists. The box could not be found.

Comment: Does the URL for the box exist and is valid? If so, here's an example of how I used it: `vagrant box add ubuntu-1464 https://github.com/kraksoft/vagrant-box-ubuntu/releases/download/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-amd64.box` . And then, in my vagrant file I just configured the box name to be `ubuntu-1464` and I removed the URL. This made vagrant find it in the list of locally installed boxes.

Comment: I tried downloading from github as well but still the same. Also I downloaded the box file manually and tried to `vagrant box add name local_box_file` but still it is throwing the same error.

Comment: And in your Vagrantfile, you referenced it as the local name, and removed the URL, right?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the complete box URL line

Comment: Could it be related to the version of vagrant? I notice that I have `1.8.5` locally.

Comment: Mine is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122707/discussion-between-sid-and-geo).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem and fixed it by installing the latest version of vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

It kept telling me :The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate

I searched for it and found the same error in this repo chat :

https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/13102

The solution (for me at least) was to add this line to the vagrant file:
at the line where it begins : Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

add this line below it : config.vm.box_download_options = {"ssl-no-revoke" => true}

so the final form should be :

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    // leave any already written lines as it is 

    config.vm.box_download_options = {"ssl-no-revoke" => true}
```

then save the file

It worked for me and completed the download

Note : this solution may have cause tiny security issues for your machine , because it effectively disables SSL certificate revocation checks during the download of the base box image for your virtual machine , but i am posting this as it was the only way I personally found to help me solve this problem.