# What is the url to the ubuntu/xenial64 box url for vagrant?

Tags: vagrant

Where to find the url for the ubuntu/xenial64.box?

I only see version-info at https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64. But what is the url for the box download?

I simply do:

```
$ vagrant init ubuntu/xenial64
$ vagrant up
```

But get:

```
The box 'ubuntu/xenial64' could not be found.
```

So I guess I need to put something in `config.vm.box_url`, but what?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325033/vagrant-box-could-not-be-found-error

Answer (score 6):

If you keep clicking around and following the links on the Vagrant Cloud website, then eventually you find that the box is hosted at http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com

From there, you can find the latest version of the xenial box specifically hosted at: 
http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/

Direct link to Vagrant box: http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant.box

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, was version mismatch. Newer vagrant works just fine.
I had Vagrant 1.4.x (on linux mint 17.1) and virtualbox 5. Online boxes were not found. Now I have Vagrant 1.8.1 (on linux mint 18.2) and virtualbox 5 and everything works as expected from the Vagrant manual (no url needed).

Thanks and sorry for waisting your time..

-- 
Oscar.